# Access same class with written data across multiple files

Tags: python

## My sample code

```py
# file1.py
global Internal

class Internal:
    ...

# file2.py
import file1
import file3

myobject.Internal = Internal(do_stuff="foo")
# file3.py
import file1

print(Internal.do_stuff)
>> foo
```

How do I make this work?
I need my code to write variables to class whenever and read whenever and work across the whole project's runtime.

Answer (score 0):

file3 knows nothing about what is happening in file2

what you should add in file3 is :

```
from file2 import *
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because I will be importing file3 to file2.

Comment: i think you ll be importing file2 to file3

Comment: No I need to import a function from file3 to file2, so it would cause a loop.